# Dismiss to RootViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an RegistrationViewController and a LoginViewController:

LoginViewController is my InitialViewController/RootViewController.

If i registrate and click on the Registrate-Button, it will push automatically to the MainViewController. If i push the Logout-Button, it dismissed to the RegistrationViewController, this is because i use [self dismissModalViewController animated:YES].

```
  - (IBAction)logoutPressed:(id)sender {
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
```

How can i Dismiss to the LoginViewController if i push the Logout-Button.

Answer (score 6):

```
-(void)dismissToRootViewController
{
    UIViewController *vc = self;
    while (vc.presentingViewController) {
        vc = vc.presentingViewController;
    }
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the UINavigationController method `-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`.

```
- (IBAction)logoutPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If you're instead talking about several modal views being presented one on top of another, you can dismiss all of them by sending `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` or the older `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to the lowest one in the stack, as described in the documentation:

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a
>   stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view
>   controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.
>   When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated
>   fashion

Comment: sry guys i forgot to mention that the Login and the Registration are Modalview. So this code does not work

Comment: @Bashud Edited to explain what to do in the case of modal view controllers. However, your question did say 'push', which implies that they were pushed onto a navigation stack. That's why I focussed initially on popping from the navigation stack.

Answer (score 3):

Try it, worked for me.

```
 [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stack of View Controllers using UINavigationController, It is wise to use following methods.

```
1. Pop the current top ViewController use
 [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

2. Pop to RootViewController use
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

3. For that matter popping to any ViewController use
 [[self navigationController] popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```